# How do I get some greek letters italic while using \usepackage[symbolgreek, italic]{mathastext}

Tags: fonts, greek, italic, mathastext

I'm using `\usepackage[symbolgreek, italic]{mathastext}` because its the only solution I found to get the desired fonts for my Greek letters. Now I need some of these letters italic. I tried the italic option of the `mathastext` package (which would turn all italic) which didn't work. Is there any option?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: which font you use?

Comment: You would want `LGRgreek` to load an arbitrary, LGR-encoded Greek font. Very few of those come in italic shape, but GFS Olga is a more-slanted companion to GFS Porson. Another PDFTeX-compatible way to load a LGR-encoded Greek font in math mode is `isomath`. Some font packages, including `newtxmath` and `newpxmath`, have a slanted-Greek option.

Comment: If you aren’t forced to use legacy software, you have the much more powerful `\setmathfont` command from `unicode-math`, such as `\setmathfont[range=it/{greek,Greek}]{Some Italic Font}`. All Unicode math fonts also come with italic and upright Greek alphabets out of the box. You also have the `\setmathsfont` command of `mathspec`.